# Hardware support for cloud containers

Tags: docker, containers, virtualization

Like virtualization using VMs, we know that new circuits add extensions to handle that kind of virtualization. I am wondering if with containers such extensions exist, or maybe is there any study for a potential hardware support for containerization even if it happens in the OS level by default.
thank you.

Comment: so I am pretty sure windows just added some kind of native support (might be software in the os) for docker so now it uses something other than hyperv for containers which is pretty cool. Like windows is running *nix natively to acheive this which is interesting

Comment: yea heard about that, but i've heard nothing about like intel our amd doing some work to support this kind of technology. Or maybe lets say apple adding something on there laptops to enhance container security. I am looking for some king of hardware stuff .

Answer (score 0):

Containers are not using hardware virtualization. Instead, they leverage built-in Linux functionality: namespaces and control groups.

**Namespaces** provided by the Linux kernel to allow separation of process ID space (PID), 
and **control groups** allow accurate resource control to limit CPU or memory usage for each container.

So there is little need for special hardware support to run containers in 64-bit Linux.
(Windows and Mac are a different story)

Comment: Exactly, the need is here what about the offers ?

Comment: Do you mean for specific Windows use cases such as SQL Server ?

Comment: i don't know how to formulate this. I know that there is a huge problem with container's security, and there is a huge effort made to counterbalance that. The fact is every thing is either implemented in the kernel level or we add another circuit which guarantees security in general let's say like TPMs. is there such a circuit specialized in container's security.Containers are running in big platforms we are talking here about cloud. So it could be interesting if intel maybe develop something resolving this kind of problem. that's what i  call hardware support for containers